# Mysterious disappearing entity association

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a long running function that goes over my `Company` records and gets matching `CompaniesHouseRecords` from an API with my `CompanySearch()` method.  This method makes a Json API call and returns a list of detatched `CompaniesHouseRecords` (the `CompanySearch()` method does not create any database context).

I then check to see if the `CompaniesHouseRecord` exists.  If it does I instantiate it, if it doesn't I add it to the database so either way it gets an ID and is tracked by the context.

I then check to see if the `Company` record contains this `CompaniesHouseRecord` and if it doesn't I add the association.

Everything appears to work fine.  Typically each search returns 20 `CompaniesHouseRecord`.  I noticed after running a while that the records at the start had lost their `CompaniesHouseRecords`.

I reset the flags and run the loop again.  All the `CompaniesHouseRecords` still exist but on this pass it is re-associating all the missing ones.  After a while the ones at the start lost their associations again.

I guessed that what happens is a company with a similar name contains the same `CompaniesHouseRecord` in it's search results and when it was assigned to one it removed it from the other.  I added a fluent api many-to-many mapping but the problem still occurs. (there is a CompanyCompaniesHouseRecord table in database)

I wrote a test function that tries to associate a `CompaniesHouseRecord` with multiple `Companies` and it works fine.  I also ran a query on the database to bring back all `CompaniesHouseRecords` that have more than one `Company` record and I can see there are planty with multiple relations so it seems like there is no problem adding multiple references but for some reason each time the process runs, after a while the associations of the records at the beginning start to disappear.

It must be a problem with my logic but I can't see it.  The process takes a long time to run so this has taken up days of my time trying to figure out.

Here is the method, can anyone see why the associations would be disappearing?

```
public static void CheckCompanyRecords()
{
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
    {

        total = db.Companies
            .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == false)
            .Count();
    }
    while (count < total)
    {
        using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
        {
            var toCheck = db.Companies

                .Include(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords)
                .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == false)
                .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
                .Skip(count)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var company in toCheck)
            {
                Messages.Output("Searching for: " + company.Name);
                List<CompaniesHouseRecord> chrl = CompanySearch(company.Name).Result;
                Messages.Output("Found        : " + chrl.Count().ToString());

                int added = 0;
                int exist = 0;
                int assigned = 0;

                if (chrl.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var chr in chrl)
                    {
                        //initiate chr record
                        CompaniesHouseRecord foundCompany;
                        if (db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Any(x => x.CompanyNumber == chr.CompanyNumber))
                        {
                            foundCompany = db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Single(x => x.CompanyNumber == chr.CompanyNumber);
                            exist++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foundCompany = chr;
                            db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Add(foundCompany);
                            added++;
                        }

                        //add and then save if its not already associated
                        if (!company.CompaniesHouseRecords.Any(x => x.ID == foundCompany.ID))
                        {
                            company.CompaniesHouseRecords.Add(foundCompany);
                            assigned++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                company.CheckedCompaniesHouse = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                count++;
                Messages.Output("Added New    : " + added.ToString());
                Messages.Output("Already Exist: " + exist.ToString());
                Messages.Output("Assigned     : " + assigned.ToString());
                Messages.Output("");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

So I looked at the IDs that are being re-assigned and they are very high like 600,000 id but they should have a low id as they were the first ones to be added.

This seems to say that at some point the existing `CompaniesHouseRecord` gets deleted and a new record gets created but without its existing association but I can see nothing in my code that would do that.

The only thing I can think of is that the `CompanyNumber` is not unique but I am enforcing this in the entity class like this:

```
[StringLength(100)]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
```

edit:

I left process running in debugging for a few hours and noticed `Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe` was taking up 2gb of ram.  My debgging session either throws a timeout or outofmemory exception if i leave it running too long.

I am wondering if this causes the unexpected behaviour somehow or if it is only happening in the debugging session?

Comment: As far as I know, `db.CompaniesHouseRecords.Add(foundCompany);` will not assign the `foundCompany.ID`, but it will be assigned in `db.SaveChanges();` This means, that `if (!company.CompaniesHouseRecords.Any(x => x.ID == foundCompany.ID))` probably doesn't do anything useful in case of newly added entries.

Comment: Should I call `db.SaveChanges()` directly after each one is added?

Comment: You are right, new ones were not getting assigned.  Not sure why some were getting removed but that doesn't seem to be happening now.  I have to say thanks a lot for spotting this.  It takes about 8 days to fully run this process so it has been a pain having to keep re-doing it.  I added a save after new record is added.

Comment: what i dont understand is why when the id is null it doesnt result in false and add the association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since newly added `foundCompany` entries don't have their `ID` set until `db.SaveChanges()` is called, the following could happen:

1st time, `!company.CompaniesHouseRecords.Any(x => x.ID == foundCompany.ID)` should evaluate to true for each company. But all following occasions would evaluate with a `0` or `null` as `ID` on both sides of the comparison and therefore they would not be added.

Make sure to use appropriate comparison criteria for not-yet-saved entities or just save intermediate results before using their ID (seems you already tried that with success after my comment). An alternative to the many saves might be to move `company.CompaniesHouseRecords.Add(foundCompany);` unconditionally into the `else` block and nest the conditional `Add` into the `if-then` block where the existing `foundCompany` entry is retrieved.

Comment: Thanks it really helped.  I still don't understand though why `x.ID` evaluates to true when compared to `null/0`.  `company` always has an ID as it is populated from database.

Comment: @Guerrilla When you have two **new** `CompaniesHouseRecords`, they both don't have an `ID` yet and you want to add them both to the `company.CompaniesHouseRecords` collection. The `company.ID` value is not used in this part of the code.

Comment: oooh now I get it.  After first pass it is actually true.  Sorry for being such a nitwit and thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.  Took a long time for the penny to drop on this one

Comment: @Guerrilla I'm always glad to help someone who already spent hours and days on a problem before asking ;). Finding a solution tends to be much more satisfying than the *"I get some random exception, here's my code"* questions.